# How to listen and get events in solidity

Tags: solidity, events

I'm using a smart contract that create posts , and i want to trigger the creation of a post , i want to listen to an event and pass the result to a node js server 
This is my event :

```
event PostCreated(
    uint id,
    string content,
    uint tipAmount,
    address payable author
);
```

and this is how i emitted it :

```
function createPost(string memory _content) public  {
        //Require valid content
        require(bytes(_content).length > 0,"Length problem");
        //Increment the post count
        postCount ++;
        //Create the post
        posts[postCount] = Post(postCount,_content,0,msg.sender);
        //Trigger Event
        emit PostCreated(postCount,_content,0,msg.sender);

    }
```

Comment: More information (including an example) on the web3js documentation: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events